# how to use cv::cuda::cvtColor() in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator

Hi there I have a question. I am a quite newbie in opencv and Qt. But function cv::cuda::cvtColor() doesn't seem work, below I will post my code. My OS is linux ubuntu 1604. opencv version is 4.1, Qt version is 5.14.0

```
int main()
{

    cv::Mat image, grayImage;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat grayImage_gpu;
    image = cv::imread("/path/to/image/image.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat image_gpu(image);
    cv::cuda::cvtColor(image_gpu, grayImage_gpu, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    grayImage_gpu.download(grayImage);

    cv::namedWindow("Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Image", grayImage);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, I mean it doesn't convert color image to grayscale one

Comment: grayImage_gpu  output is a color image ?

Comment: no, grayImage_pu is a grayscale image, the input called image is color image

Comment: try to access gpuMat values to check if the image was loaded correctly and it's 3 channels.

Comment: so how can I check it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372262/access-pixels-in-gpumat

Comment: I found that it actually converts image to grayscale but when I call cv::imshow() fuction for displaying that, it  shows me the color image? Any suggestions?

Comment: initialize   "grayImage"  as 1 channel Mat before using it.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: cv::Mat grayImage= cv::Mat(width, height, CV_8UC1);